# Share all products per web site

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, adminhtml

So, I create + 2 websites with store and store views. I need to set all my products to all this web sites. Possible ways:

1. Manually per product(but I have more than 200 000 products)
2. In Manage products -> select all and update attributes (but I it will take a lot of time)
3. Make a query to DB

Is any one resolve this problem with query? what tables should I take?

Comment: keep in mind that 'INSERT INTO catalog_product_website with SELECT from catalog_product_entity' you need consider products without website and not visible singly(these types does not need in catalog_product_website table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between products an websites is remembered in `catalog_product_website`.
Insert one line for each combination of product and website in there.

```
INSERT INTO
    `catalog_product_website`
VALUES
    (1,1),
    (1,2),
....
    (200000, 1),
    (200000, 2),
```

You might want to split this into more queries because you can reach the limit for the max allowed query size.

When you are done reindex (this will take a lot of time so be patient)

Comment: Thanks! so may I use loop in which I will set this query?

Comment: Sure, you can loop through all the products and insert 2 lines in the table `catalog_product_website` for each product, if the line does not already exist.

Comment: Hm also I think about something like: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_website` ('product_id', 'website_id') SELECT entity_id , 2 from `catalog_product_entity`....

Comment: That could work. I just told you where you need to add something....how you add it?...choose your weapon.

Comment: Finall. Did. Thanks for advice!!! Really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to update product website programmatically,

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach( $products as $product) {
    $product->setStoreId($storeId); // replace $storeId by STORE ID
    $product->setWebsiteIDs($websiteid); // replace $websiteid by WEBSITEID
    try {
        $product->save();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's `setWebsiteIds()` instead of `setStoreId`  and this won't work for 200k products.

Comment: yes marius, you are right `setWebsiteIds()`.